# Is it ok to store many null values in my table?

Tags: mysql, null

I am creating a table for bookmarks in my database as the following picture, the bookmark can be on a place or an event,  then it can be be regular user or by business user:

e.g.  business user with id (1) made a bookmark on place id (1)
e.g.  business user with id (2) made a bookmark on event id (6)

in such a way my table contains the following indexes to allow only for single bookmark for place or event by any user.

Table structure with indexes

[image]
but then the table looks like this when I insert values for bookmarks:

[image: values of bookmarks]

my question is what is the effect on storing a table like this on database, can I improve the table structure without making many small tables of it?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok if you have an algorithm of dealing with the null values when you try to read data from your table.